# How do you delete the last node in a (min-) heap?

Tags: algorithm, tree, heap, binary-tree

I'm learning for an exam and currently I'm at heaps. I have understood how to delete a node from a heap but I could find a case where I cannot use the algorithm to delete.

The problem is I want delete `15` which is a leaf and the last node of the min heap. When you delete a node in a heap, you are looking for the last node of the heap, replace it with the deletion node and check if the children of this node are greater than it.. then continue this recursively.

For this reason (`15` is last element and has no children), I don't know how to delete it.

```
        1
     /     \
    9       6
   / \     /
 17  11   8
 /
15
```

I would think that you can just delete it without doing anything else. You basically replace it by itself since the deletion node = last node..? So it looks like that:

```
        1
     /     \
    9       6
   / \     /
 17  11   8
```

I hope you can help  me, I really need to know that for my exam and I couldn't find anything about that case on the internet.

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing last node is very simple task - just remove it, nothing to do more (except for decrementing counter and resizing array if needed). In general function swapping item with itself change nothing (while useless work is done), but you can check whether item is the last and omit swap.

Note that removing non-head element is rare problem (you have to provide explicit access to it), most algorithms use only the topmost element.

Note also that your picture does not show valid binary heap, because heap is **complete** binary tree, and all levels (except for the last) must be filled completely, but your tree has empty place in the third row.

Comment: A follow-up question from me if that is OK: removing any element from a *binary* heap is as easy as replacing it with the last element and performing heapify; is the same possible with *any* heap (e.g. Fibonacci) structure?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: The deletion method you describe works for a binary heap (actually, an n-ary heap). But other heap types have much different structures and much different rules for maintaining their structure when a node is deleted.

Comment: @JimMischel that's what I had in mind, just wanted to check. Thank you

Comment: @meowgoesthedog But there is no explicit/apparent last item in fib. heap and binomial heap. And removing arbitrary element in these structures, AFAIK, is performed through key changing to +/- infinity to make it topmost

Comment: To your last note; Does that mean that I have chosen a bad example or can I make it correct by just adding empty nodes?

Comment: @Hamudii It is enough to add right child to `6` node

Comment: So it's fine if I just add a right child to 6 node which is empty?